# Back Button for Scrolling Table (not page/window)

Tags: javascript

I have a two column table with over 200 terms and definitions.  It scrolls to #anchors by a select dropdown that triggers a *scrollIntoView* function called "showIt".  It also scrolls to #anchors using hrefs.  You can try them at   http://poweranddata.info/knowledge-center/terminology. You can also try them and see a sample of the full code at  http://jsbin.com/IBePAFo/2/edit.

What I need now is a back button that will scroll back to the previous row scrolled to.  That's it.  Don't need to save a long history (at least not for now). Also, would prefer not to save a position and scroll back to it if possible.

I think the basic onclick button function might be as simple as 1st) copying the current row id, 2nd) activating the *scrollintoView* function (shown below) using the previous scrolled to row id that is stored somewhere, and then 3) replacing the stored previous scrolled to row id with the copied one, which makes the Back button ready for the next click.  Maybe onload could store the first row id by default so that the Back button always has something to start with (or maybe not necessary).

I've gotten this far, but just really having a hard time getting my head rapped around this.  Have searched all the forums from every angle I could think of, including back buttons, history, cookies, tables -- you name it.  I couldn't find any code specific enough for this.  Just about everything seems to only apply to pages and windows.  I would be so grateful to anyone who could help me with this code.

Code below provided for quick reference. Same as in jsbin above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 

<style>    

body { 
    font: 20px Calibri, Serif;
    display: block;
    width:500px;
    margin:0 0 0 0;}

table { 
    display: block; /* makes it sizeable */
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;  /*height of scrollable area */
    overflow: auto; /* scroll rather than overflow */
    overflow-x:true; /* Bottom Scroll Bar */
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin:0 0 0 0;
    border:1px solid #ccc;} 

tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background: #eee; } /* Zebra striping */

th { 
    background: #333; /*Not used - No headers*/
    color: white; /*Not used - No headers*/
    font-weight: bold; /*Not used - No headers*/
}
td, th { 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    text-align: left; 
}
td  {vertical-align:text-top; padding:6px 10px 6px 10px; }  

table.fixed table {width:500px;} /*setup for col widths */
table.fixed td:nth-of-type(1) {width:200px;} /*sets col width */
table.fixed td:nth-of-type(2) {width:300px;} /*sets col width */  

</style> 

<!--FUNCTIONfor: SCROLL-INTO-VIEW (used for select dropdown and top & bottom buttons)-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function showIt(elID) {
var el = document.getElementById(elID);
el.scrollIntoView(true);}

</script>

<!--FUNCTIONfor: RESETING SELECT DROPDOWN-->      
<script type="text/javascript">
function resetScrollTo() {
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
elements[i].selectedIndex = 0;
}
}
</script>   

<!--FUNCTIONfor: BACK BUTTON ???????????????-->     




</head>

<body>

<div style="margin:0 0 10px 0;"> <!--Dropdown/button CONTAINER-->   

<!--BOX: SCROLL-TO ("showIt")--> 
<select class="box-select_scrollto" id="box-select_scrollto"     onchange="showIt(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"> 
<option value="scroll-to" selected>SCROLL-TO</option> 
<option value="absorber">absorber</option>
<option value="accessible">accessible</option>
<option value="adjustable">adjustable</option>
<option value="ampacity">ampacity</option>
<option value="ampere">ampere</option>
<option value="appliance">appliance</option>
<option value="approved">approved</option>
<option value="askarel">askarel</option>
<option value="automatic">automatic</option>
<option value="coulomb">coulomb</option>
<option value="current">current</option>
<option value="cutout">cutout</option>
<option value="cutout box">cutout box</option>
<option value="data">data</option>
<option value="data server">data server</option>
<option value="data storage">data storage</option>
<option value="dead front">dead front</option>
</select> 

<button class="buttonTop" type="button" onclick="resetScrollTo()">Reset</button>
<button class="buttonTop" type="button" onclick="showIt('top');     resetScrollTo();">Top</button>
<button class="buttonBottom" type="button" onclick="showIt('bottom')">Bottom</button>
<button class="buttonBottom" type="button" onclick="back()">Back</button>

</div>  

<table class="fixed" class="sortable" id="termtable" name="termtable">

<tr><td id="top">Top row</td><td>Top row</td></tr>
<tr><td id="absorber">absorber</td><td>Definition  includes <a style="color: #04b404;"     href="#cutout">cutout</a></td></tr>  
<tr><td id="accessible">Definition</td><td>Definition includes  <a style="color:     #04b404;" href="#dead front">dead front</a></td></tr>
<tr><td id="adjustable">adjustable</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="ampacity">ampacity</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="ampere">ampere</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="appliance">appliance</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="approved">approved</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="askarel">askarel</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="automatic">automatic</td><td>Definition</td></tr>  
<tr><td id="coulomb">coulomb</td><td>Definition</td></tr>   
<tr><td id="current">current</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="cutout">cutout</td><td>Definition includes  <a style="color: #04b404;"     href="#absorber">absorber</a></td></tr>
<tr><td id="cutout box">cutout box</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="data">data</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="data server">data server</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="data storage">data storage</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="dead front">dead front</td><td>Definition includes  <a style="color: #04b404;" href="#accessible">accessible</a></td></tr>
<tr><td id="bottom">Bottom row</td><td>Bottom row</td></tr>  

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed your jquery and replaced it with other JS.  The reset button basically is not needed with this code so it can be removed.

In order for a "Back" button to work, you actually have to "go" to another page... a totally new URL. This script does that and allows you to move back incrementally... go to top... or bottom.

Try this...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style>    
body { 
font: 20px Calibri, Serif;
display: block;
width:500px;
margin:0 0 0 0;}

table { 
display: block; /* makes it sizeable */
width: 500px;
height: 100px;  /*height of scrollable area */
overflow: auto; /* scroll rather than overflow */
overflow-x:true; /* Bottom Scroll Bar */
border-collapse: collapse;
margin:0 0 0 0;
border:1px solid #ccc;} 

tr:nth-of-type(odd) { background: #eee; } /* Zebra striping */

th { 
background: #333; /*Not used - No headers*/
color: white; /*Not used - No headers*/
font-weight: bold; /*Not used - No headers*/
}
td, th { 
border: 1px solid #ccc; 
text-align: left; 
}
td  {vertical-align:text-top; padding:6px 10px 6px 10px; }  

table.fixed table {width:500px;} /*setup for col widths */
table.fixed td:nth-of-type(1) {width:200px;} /*sets col width */
table.fixed td:nth-of-type(2) {width:300px;} /*sets col width */  
</style> 
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--//
function MM_goToURL() { //v3.0
var i, args=MM_goToURL.arguments; document.MM_returnValue = false;
for (i=0; i<(args.length-1); i+=2) eval(args[i]+".location='"+args[i+1]+"'");
}

function MM_jumpMenu(targ,selObj,restore){ //v3.0
eval(targ+".location='"+selObj.options[selObj.selectedIndex].value+"'");
if (restore) selObj.selectedIndex=0;
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin:0 0 10px 0;">
<select class="box-select_scrollto" id="box-select_scrollto" onchange="MM_jumpMenu('parent',this,1)"> 
  <option value="scroll-to" selected>SCROLL-TO</option> 
  <option value="#absorber">absorber</option>
  <option value="#accessible">accessible</option>
  <option value="#adjustable">adjustable</option>
  <option value="#ampacity">ampacity</option>
  <option value="#ampere">ampere</option>
  <option value="#appliance">appliance</option>
  <option value="#approved">approved</option>
  <option value="#askarel">askarel</option>
  <option value="#automatic">automatic</option>
  <option value="#coulomb">coulomb</option>
  <option value="#current">current</option>
  <option value="#cutout">cutout</option>
  <option value="#cutout box">cutout box</option>
  <option value="#data">data</option>
  <option value="#data server">data server</option>
  <option value="#data storage">data storage</option>
  <option value="#dead front">dead front</option>
</select>
<button class="buttonTop" type="button" onclick="MM_goToURL('parent','#top');return document.MM_returnValue;">Top</button>
<button class="buttonBottom" type="button" onclick="MM_goToURL('parent','#bottom');return document.MM_returnValue;">Bottom</button>
<script>
<!--//
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var browserName  = navigator.appName;
var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
browserName = "Firefox";
} 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=1) {
browserName = "Other";
}

if (browserName == 'Firefox'){
document.write(''
+'<button class="buttonBottom" type="button" onclick="history.back();location.reload(forceGet=true);">FF-Back</button>')
}

if (browserName != 'Firefox'){
document.write(''
+'<button class="buttonBottom" type="button" onclick="history.back();">Back</button>')
}
//-->
</script>
</div>  

<table class="fixed sortable" id="termtable" name="termtable">
<tr><td class="topBotRow1" id="top"><a name="top" id="top"></a>Electrical Term</td> <!--"top" FOR TOP BUTTON-->
<tr><td id="absorber">absorber</td><td>Definition  includes <a style="color: #04b404;"     href="#cutout">cutout</a></td></tr>  
<tr><td id="accessible">Definition</td><td>Definition includes  <a style="color:     #04b404;" href="#dead front">dead front</a></td></tr>
<tr><td id="adjustable">adjustable</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="ampacity">ampacity</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="ampere">ampere</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="appliance">appliance</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="approved">approved</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="askarel">askarel</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="automatic">automatic</td><td>Definition</td></tr>  
<tr><td id="coulomb">coulomb</td><td>Definition</td></tr>   
<tr><td id="current">current</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="cutout">cutout</td><td>Definition includes  <a style="color: #04b404;"     href="#absorber">absorber</a></td></tr>
<tr><td id="cutout box">cutout box</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="data">data</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="data server">data server</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="data storage">data storage</td><td>Definition</td></tr>
<tr><td id="dead front">dead front</td><td>Definition includes  <a style="color: #04b404;" href="#accessible">accessible</a></td></tr>
<tr><td id="bottom">Bottom row</td><td>Bottom row</td></tr>  
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Working example can be seen here... http://siteprevue.net/stackoverflow/scrollto.htm

---

**CHANGES:**

1) Added `<a name="top" id="top"></a>` to the first row of the table.
  This creates a named anchor on the page and doesn't rely on browser interpretation.

2) Replaced the "Back" button code with javascript.  This script first determines if the browser is Firefox or not.  Next it writes one set of code for the button if it's Firefox and another set of code for all other browsers.

This code was tested in Chrome 29.0.1547.66 m, Firefox 23.0.1, IE 8.0.6001.18702 and Safari 5.0.5 (7533.21.1).

Downside... in order for Firefox to "go back" the page has to be re-loaded with the previous URL. This is due to the fact that your table is wrapped inside a DIV.

Notice when you load the above sample page in Firefox the back button reads "FF-Back". This was for testing purposes to make sure the correct button was loading in the above mentioned browsers.

---

... and please don't forget to accept this as your answer if it works for you. :)

Comment: John, I love your code.  It reduced mine, eliminated need for reset button, back button has history, and is lightning fast.  However, while the select dropdown works great in you jsbin, in my test page is tries to go to another page and gets a 404 message.

Comment: Also, the top and bottom buttons work great. You can check it out here: http://poweranddata.info/termtest-in-prog  Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at your code... you need to add the "#" before your option values, like this...

    <option value="#absorber">absorber</option>

This indicates an "anchor" on the page.  Without it the server assumes that it should go to a **page** named "absorber" appended to the current URL.

Of course this page doesn't exist, ergo the 404 error. :)

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please don't forget to "accept" it.  That's what helps those of us answering questions to continue to help others.

Comment: Adding the "#" before the option values in the select was the missing piece.  I forgot that your code is URL based.  Though my code worked, it was not URL based and therefore didn't need it.  Your code does more with less lines of code. The table really flies now.

Comment: Cross Browser Issues: Chrome- Everything works. IE- Top and Back buttons don't work.  FF- only Back button doesn't work.  See it here: [link] (http://poweranddata.info/knowledge-center/terminology).  Your thoughts?

Comment: I added a named anchor for "top" and replaced the back button with javascript. Take a look at the changes in the code above.

Comment: Excellent! Now just need to figure out Top and Back button for IE 10.0.9.  For now I added back my 'showIt' function to get the Top button to work there.  Any solutions for IE 10 Back button would be great (preferably not requiring page reload like Firefox, which is very slow).  See latest code here...(href="http://jsbin.com/IBePAFo/16)  Note: For some reason some functions that work in the website don't work in jsbin! See it here...(http://poweranddata.info/termtest-in-prog). Thanks